# Selenium 2 Java Run / Deploy jar in Selenium server

Tags: java, selenium, jar, intellij-idea

I have been searching around for some Selenium server setup answers but I have yet to find anything definitive. I have a remote server running at 10.x.x.x with selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar which I can run using the command:

java –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar

That works great and I can visit the hub at http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub which then brings up a page with two options: (1) Create Session and (2) Refresh Session. When I create a session with Firefox an empty webpage is painted on the screen and the hub page now has the following options: (1) Take Screenshot, (2) Delete Session, and (3) Load Script. All seems to be well at this point.

Using IntelliJ on my local system I have created a number of tests with selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar as a dependency. Those tests run fine out of the IDE and I can create an artifact such as myTests.jar and run that locally as well. I SCP the myTests.jar file to the remote server and run that file via VNC using java –jar myTests.jar. Now that works great as well. So far so good.

My question is this. How do I use Selenium server to run myTests.jar? Do I even need to use Selenium to do this? I thought about writing a bash script that loops myTests.jar to run every hour or something along those lines but I would prefer to use Selenium if possible. I have looked at (code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) but I haven’t found a way to do this or if I should be using Selenium this way at all. Any assistance would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to setup a Selenium Grid. Give this a shot.

On your server start the selenium hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub
```

On your local system start the server as a node

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.x.x.x:4444/wd/register
```

Check http://10.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub to make sure your machine registered with the hub. Then you should be able to start your tests from the server. Make sure you define a RemoteWebDriver otherwise the tests will try to start on the local server.

I would also recommend that you use Ant to build and run your tests. Using bash scripts works well but I personally find it easier to use Ant.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This really gets me going in the right direction. I need to get our Networking team to open some ports for me but at least I know the direction now.

Comment: Great glad I could be of help!

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up? I have the hub running and I can view the config here: 127.x.x.1:4444/grid/console and I can see the correct DefaultRemoteProxy listening on: http://x.x.x.x:5555. The node has successfully registered to the hub with: http://10.x.x.x:4444/grid/register. All is well so far. It looks like I am getting an error at: http://10.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub.

Comment: Here is the error: {"status":13,"value":{"class":"java.lang.NullPointerException","stackTrace":[{"fileName":"ExternalSessionKey.java","lineNumber":73,"className":"org.openqa.grid.internal.ExternalSessionKey","methodName":"fromWebDriverRequest"}, ...Anyhow, it's a pretty long error. It looks like I am getting a 500 server error at http://10.x.x.x:4444/grid/register as well.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo but make sure you register the node with "java -jar .... -r node -hub **"http://127.x.x.1:4444/wd/register"** it looks like you're using "grid/register" if I'm reading it correctly

Comment: Thanks again! I think I have everything working now. When I run my jar I run that from a node, correct? I am setting my driver with: driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub"), capability); And that seems to work. I think. What is supposed to happen in the hub side? It seems to be up and running but how do I validate that.

Comment: No, your tests should be started from the hub. Assuming your hub is some server and the node is your local machine, the browser should be started remotely on your local client. If you're running both the hub and node in the same machine then you won't be able to tell much difference since the browser will just launch locally. Also your RemoteWebDriver should be on port 4444 unless you started the hub on a different port. Port 5555 is normally the port the node uses to connect.